# My switch is not recognizing the variable I defined before it

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm coding a rock paper scissors game for a chatbot. The issue I'm running into is that the `switch (playerChoice)` is not recognizing the string defined in the `playerChoice` variable.

When I run the switch, the default case always outputs. It would seem that it's not even picking up the variable in the switch()

Here is my code, with comments:

```
var user = "user"
var message = "/rps rock" //this can be paper or scissors, based on the user's input.
//Here we find out what the player chose from the command '/rps [choice]'
var playerSaid = message.split(" ")
var playerChoice = playerSaid[1].toString()

//This determines the bot's choice of 1-3
var botChoice = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1)

//This switch *should* find the user's choice
//The if statements inside each case should get the bot's choice and tell the verdict appropriately
switch (playerChoice) {
  case "rock":
    if (botChoice = 1) {
      var rpsVerdict = "It\'s a tie!"
    } else if (botChoice = 2) {
      var rpsVerdict = "Botticus wins!"
    } else if (botChoice = 3) {
      var rpsVerdict = user + " wins!"
    };
    break;
  case "paper":
    if (botChoice = 1) {
      var rpsVerdict = "It\'s a tie!"
    } else if (botChoice = 2) {
      var rpsVerdict = "Botticus wins!"
    } else if (botChoice = 3) {
      var rpsVerdict = user + " wins!"
    };
    break;
  case "scissors":
    if (botChoice = 1) {
      var rpsVerdict = "It\'s a tie!"
    } else if (botChoice = 2) {
      var rpsVerdict = "Botticus wins!"
    } else if (botChoice = 3) {
      var rpsVerdict = user + " wins!"
    };
    break;
  default:
    var rpsVerdict = "default"
    break
  }

//Here we output a simple sentence telling who won.
console.log('You chose ' + playerChoice + '. I chose ' + botChoice + '. ' + rpsVerdict)
```

(I realize the botChoice outputs a number, rather than a string)

Comment: I get the following in log: You chose rock. I chose 1. It's a tie! works for me

Comment: I run your code with a debugger and I always enter in the "rock" case - it all seems to be working for me.

Comment: Side note: The array entries in the array you get from `split` are strings, so there's no need to call `.toString()` on them.

Comment: I recommend you review the rules for where semicolons go. You've left off most of them above (which means you're relying on JS's "automatic semicolon insertion" error-correction mechanism), but then have a couple scattered about in the wrong places (you don't want a semicolon after the block attached to an `if` or `else`, for instance). Also recommend declaring your variables **once**, not in *10 different places* (in the case of `rpsVerdict`). Again JS is lenient here, ignoring repeated declarations and hosting them out of control structures to the top of the function, but...

Comment: It might be important to note that this is being run in node.js.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yeah I realize the semicolons are messed up (the program we used had strange rules set at first)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks, I'll try all of your recommendations

Comment: @saranshkataria Try choosing something else. It seems to always return 1 for bot, and state that it's a tie.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the comparison in your `if` statements:

```
if (botChoice = 1) {
// -----------^
```

`=` is the *assignment* operator. To compare, you want `==` or `===` (doesn't matter which in this case).

With the assignment, here's what you're really doing:

```
botChoice = 1
if (1) {
```

...because with the assignment operator, it assigns the value to the target (`botChoice`), and the result of the operation is the value that was assigned. So you always enter the first `if` (because `1` is truthy), no matter what `botChoice` actually was from `Math.random`.

---

You don't need the `switch`, though, you can determine the winner more simply and with less repetition using a lookup.

```
// Set up data. `choices` is for using Math.random to get
// a choice for the bot. `winLookup` is for looking up the
// player's choice and seeing what it beats.
var choices = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];
var winLookup = {
    rock: "scissors",
    paper: "rock",
    scissors: "paper"
};

// Bot chooses
var botChoice = choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];

// Outcome
var rpsVerdict;
if (playerChoice == botChoice) {
    rpsVerdict = "It's a tie!";
} else if (winLookup[playerChoice] == botChoice) {
    rpsVerdict = user + " wins!";
} else {
    rpsVerdict = "Botticus wins!";
}
```

Live example:

```js
document.getElementById("play").onclick = function() {
  var choices = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];
  var winLookup = {
    rock: "scissors",
    paper: "rock",
    scissors: "paper"
  };
  var user = "user";
  var message = "/rps rock";
  var playerSaid = message.split(" ");
  var playerChoice = document.getElementById("playerChoice").value;
  //var playerChoice = playerSaid[1];
  //// No .toString() --------------^

  // botChoice => rock, paper, or scissors
  var botChoice = choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];

  // outcome
  var rpsVerdict;
  if (playerChoice == botChoice) {
    rpsVerdict = "It's a tie!";
  } else if (winLookup[playerChoice] == botChoice) {
    rpsVerdict = user + " wins!";
  } else {
    rpsVerdict = "Botticus wins!";
  }

  snippet.log(
    "You chose " + playerChoice + ". I chose " + botChoice +
    ". " + rpsVerdict
  );
};
```

```html
<label>
  Your choice:
  <select size=3 id="playerChoice">
    <option>rock</option>
    <option>paper</option>
    <option>scissors</option>
  </select>
</label>
<input type="button" id="play" value="Play">
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="//tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```